# Task Id starts from 1 for each new project

Tags: mysql, sql

Beginner level question:

I'm working on project that requires to create tasks within projects. User can create multiple projects and multiple tasks within each project. I need to assign `id` to each task and it should start from 1 (and the increment by one like primary key) for each separate project. How can achieve this in single `tasks` table? Or should I have to create a new table for tasks each time after project is created?

Comment: Use a *view* and use `row_number()` over a window.

Comment: _"and the increment by one like primary key"_ - you're conflating the term `PRIMARY KEY` with `IDENTITY` or `auto_increment`. A `PRIMARY KEY` _does not_ have to be a monotonically incrementing number.

Comment: I meant to say, value as increment number sense only.

Comment: _"How can achieve this in single tasks table?"_ - you mean like `CREATE TABLE tasks ( task_id int NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, project_id int NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT FK_projects FOREIGN KEY ( project_id ) REFERENCES projects ( project_id ) etc );` ?

Comment: Yes and also assume this - user created a project A and project B. Now, if user creates a task in A, the task id (we can save in one separate column than task_id) should start from 1 to so on. Same is true for B. if user creates task in B, the task id should start from 1 to so on for each new task.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking "How can I create a sequence generator in MySQL"

Comment: these comments so far seem to miss the "start from 1...for each separate project".  absolutely do *not* make a new tasks table for each project.  either do this with an insert trigger or do it in your client (lock the tasks table for the project, select the highest id, insert with one more than that)